# Use PHPUnit to detect any PHP Error/Warning/Exception

Tags: phpunit

I'd like to have PHPUnit fail when it encounters any PHP error, warning, or exception.

I'm seeing examples of the inverse, where

```
/**
 * @expectedException PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning
 */
```

is used when an error is expected.  But instead, I'd like to exercise various code paths and guarantee that no errors, warnings, or exceptions were thrown.

Comment: For me, the question is not precise enough to answer but it feels like you're abusing PHPunit for something which doesn't sound like proper unit testing. Again, I may be wrong since I don't get enough information from your question. Maybe you could post some example (pseudo)code of what you would like to do.

Answer (score 2):

Any test that throws an uncaught exception or raises a warning or error is automatically marked with `E` (for error) by PHPUnit without your intervention. You only need to take measures like `@expectedException` when you want to count such errors as correct behavior.